# Oracle Group By and Count

Tags: oracle

I have a table Users like:

```
ID EMAIL
1  1@yahoo.com
2  2@yahoo.com
3  3@gmail.com
```

What i want is to count how many i have on each email service and the email service name. I need a result like:

```
yahoo.com 2
gmail.com 1
```

I am trying to use

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(EMAIL,INSTR('@',EMAIL,1)+1,length(EMAIL)), count (*)
FROM Users GROUP BY EMAIL;
```

But i have an issue to Count(*).
Can you help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: The domain would be `substr(email,instr(email,'@')+1)` or `regexp_replace(email,'.*@')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(EMAIL, INSTR(EMAIL,'@')+1, length(EMAIL)) as domain, 
       count(*)
FROM Users 
GROUP BY SUBSTR(EMAIL, INSTR(EMAIL,'@')+1, length(EMAIL))
```